# RPi zero W auto power up / down by available power

Tags: boot, power-supply, power-management, shutdown, rpi

I want to run a RPi Zero W on a crude solar panel and battery or supercapacitor.

I understand the pi has an input range of 80-120A or so, and needs a minimum of just 2 volts. This makes it ideal for me.

How can I set up the Zero W to power down if the voltage gets too low, or turn on once the voltage reaches a certain threshold, and continues running, say once clouds dissipate?

Are there any guides on this? How straight forward is it? I understand electronics, but my knowledge of the RPi is limited.

Thanks

Comment: Your facts are wrong. Recommeded current capacity is 1.2Amps. Voltage is 5V. https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/develop/documentation/asciidoc/computers/raspberry-pi/power-supplies.adoc

Comment: @CoderMike then how come this link says it can consume as little as 80mA? https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-power

Comment: First you have to design your power management circuitry (which is likely to cost many times the cost of a PiZero) including voltage detection because the Pi has none. Once you have done this ask a question about how to shutdown the Pi using your detector.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not concerned about the power management circuit. That should be easy. I just dont know how to interface the signals with the RPi and configure it to react accordingly. How to signal it to shut down, and how to revive it.

Comment: Your question still says 80-120A, i assume you mean mA and 2V instead of 5V - correct your question. It may well idle at 80ma but it will likely run flat out whilst it boots requiring way more than 80ma.

Comment: You have obviously done little research. It is simple to shutdown - there  are hundreds of posts. The Pi will automatically boot when power is restored.

Comment: Miiliways, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same thing: running an RPi from a battery charged by a solar cell. Due to the fact that the **only** way to achieve zero power consumption is by removing power (true for all RPi), I designed a simple circuit to accomplish that. The design requires addition of a Real Time Clock (RTC), and use of two `overlays` in `/boot/config.txt`.

There's a schematic and more details in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/130443/83790), but this answer didn't include the RTC... if you're interested & can't find the other answers, let me know & I'll try to help.